# Как с помощью vue-router передать компоненту несколько параметров?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Возможно ли передать компоненту через router-link несколько параметров?

```
<router-link
  v-for="board in boards"
  :key="board.id"
  :to="{ name: 'board', params: { id: board.id, name: board.name}}">
  {{board.name}}
</router-link>
```

в router:

```
{
  path: '/board/:id',
  name: 'board',
  component: Board,
  props: true
}
```

При переходе на страницу компонента Board {{id}} и {{name}} через props определены, но если страницу обновить определен только id. При этом в урле кроме id больше передавать ничего не хочется

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите невозможного. Откуда в таком случае брать параметр для передачи, если его нет в урле?

Вот есть такая возможность - указать не булево значение, а функцию. Возможно это выход для вас.

[Ссылка на нужный абзац документации по Vue-Router](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: cпасибо, решил сделать так: path: '/board/:id/:name'